# Javascript window resize function that triggers only on width or height change, not both?

Tags: jquery, performance, window-resize

I would like to write a Javascript function that triggers *only* when the window width is resized, not when the window height is resized (or vice versa).

I know that the `$(window).on('resize')` function exists in jQuery. But it triggers when either the window width or height is resized; to my knowledge, it's unable to isolate changes in one dimension or the other.

I've come up with a hack-y solution that stores the previous window width as a variable, then constantly updates it when the resize function is called and compares the new value against the old. However, this solution seems unnecessarily memory-intensive for such a simple operation.

Is there an easier / less memory-intensive way to detect changes in a single window dimension?

```
    // Create a variable to store the width of the window
    var windowWidth = $(window).width();

    // When the window is resized...
    $(window).on('resize', function(){

        // If the window width has changed...
        if(windowWidth != $(window).width()) {

            // Store new window width in the variable and run my function
            windowWidth = $(window).width();

            executeMyDesiredCode();
        }
    });
```

Comment: You could examine the `event` and see if there is a detail there to help yet I suspect you will need to examine both width and height and only perform the action when height is the same and width changes.

Comment: It's not extremely elegant but more lightweight to create two fixed elements and use `ResizeObserver` on them to [detect a change](https://jsfiddle.net/cz5swtpv) in the screen size. That way both directions can be separated. There's a [workaround](https://jsfiddle.net/rf7L1jyo) to use the same method on the `window` object but you'd still have to use a pair of variables to compare them with the previous entries. You could also make you existing script lighter by throttling (or debouncing) the code that is to be executed on the `resize` event.

Comment: Thanks for these comments! Surprised there aren't better solutions here that are native to Javascript / jQuery, but good to know there are at least a few things I can do to improve efficiency.

Answer (score 3):

Just need to use a prevWidth or prevHeight variable:

With ResizeObserver:

```
var prevWidth = window.width;
var observer = new ResizeObserver(function(entries) {
    const width = entries[0].borderBoxSize?.[0].inlineSize;
    if (typeof width === 'number' && width !== prevWidth ) {
        prevWidth = width;
        console.log(width);
    }
})
observer.observe(window.document.body);
```

With onResize event:

```
var prevWidth = window.innerWidth;
window.addEventListener('resize', function() {
    if (window.innerWidth !== prevWidth ) {
        prevWidth = width;
        console.log(width);
    }
});
```

PS: just noticed you already know about this solution, but still decided to leave it here for future readers...

Comment: `window.width` is undefined. Either use `window.innerWidth` or `window.outerWidth`

Comment: Hi, can someone list example code for this? I'm still learning how to set up vars for web coding and not sure where to enter numeric values, etc.

I'm currently using this code for window size-based redirects but I would love something interactive based on  window width changes by the user:

<script type="text/javascript">
if (window.outerWidth <=900
  ) {
window.location = "https://www. your URL ";
}
</script>